# IBM Watson Assistant returning FALSE in response with # and a number

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have a list of plant numbers: (i.e. #0001). When a user asks about a plant, IBM Watson Assistant is turning "#0001" of "Plant #0001 is at Location A." with false: "Plant false is at Location A."

[image: Image 1 of False Response]

However, if I change the response with a space in between the # sign and number, to "Plant # 0001 is in Location A." it is fine.

[image: Image 2 of Non-False Response]

Even if I turn off the system entity "sys-number" it does the same thing.

Has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for return `false` is that the character `#` is used in short-hand syntax to indicate entities. You probably have not defined an entity `#0001`. Thus, the value is `false`.

If you escape the your plant number, e.g., `\#0001`, the value is printed correctly. Bottom line, if you want to print anything beginning with special characters like `@`, `$` or `#`, use the `\` in front of them to escape them.

Comment: Thank you! I did have #0001 as an entity and it printed as false anyway. The \ worked.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please upvote the answer and mark it as such.